# Oracle: Import CSV file unix

Tags: windows, csv, unix, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

i want to import csv file into oracle database using pl / sql developer, i inform you that the base is installed under linux, and pl / sql under windows, i ran the command:

```
SQL> @C:\app\session_name\product\11.2.0\client_3\BIN\sqlldr user/passwd@base_name  control=/opt/FNDBSS/Control/FNControl.txt log=log.txt;
```

but the error has appeared: Error reading file

thank you for helping me

Comment: Your control file is pointing to Linux  path - `/opt/FNDBSS/Control/FNControl.txt` and you are executing `sqlldr` in Windows. You should either have a local control file or run it in Linux command prompt.

Comment: Thanks, but in PL/SQL i connected to database installed in Linux system

Comment: @KaushikNayak seems to be suggesting you copy the FNControl.txt file to windows where you are running sqlldr (and give the correct path to it in your pl/sql command).  Did you try that?

Comment: i try in Windows but i have the same error:

Comment: SQL> @C:\app\session_name\product\11.2.0\client_3\BIN\sqlldr user/passwd  control=C:\TEST\Control2.ctl, DATA=C:\TEST\test2.csv
Error reading file

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: How can a Windows desktop tool open a Linux file? You will need to mount the Linux directory as a Samba drive or something, or else copy the file to some other drive that you can see from your desktop, making sure it is in Windows file format.

Answer (score 1):

A the least add the LOG file to the command line or your control file. It tells you what loader is doing and perhaps why. Additionally check into the BAD and DISCARD files. See the [SQL Loader concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm#g1013706) for your  Oracle version.